# Mysql Workbench priveleges, data import

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I try to change the priveleges on a mysql db I get the following error:

Please make sure the used account has rights to the MySQL grant tables. Error executing 'DESCRIBE mysql.db'

Is this also why it will not let me import tables in from another DB? When i try I get the error:

Operation failed with exitcode 1

09:20:16 Restoring D:\design and photos\boo.com\db dump\070113.sql

Running: mysql.exe --defaults-extra-file="c:\users\darren\appdata\local\temp\tmpslubjs.cnf"  --host=87.117.239.19 --user=boo8_yu52 --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments < "D:\design and photos\boo.com\db dump\070113.sql"

ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 1: Access denied for user 'boo8_yu52'@'%' to database ' boo8_6652'

It does however let me create tables manually. Can't work it out at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure that the account you are using is granted with grant option 
and the account should have permissions on mysql database in which the db grant table exits

or the best way is to assign the permission with the root account

see the link below may be useful for you

http://blog.loftninjas.org/2008/04/22/error-1044-42000-at-line-2-access-denied-for-user-root-to-database-db/